# Best way to connect 4 or 5 SATA HDDs to RasPi

Tags: hard-drive, storage, pci

I'm trying to figure out the best way to connect 4 or 5 3.5 inch SATA internal hard drives to a RasPi, haven't decided which one yet. Also, I don't want to connect a purchased 4 or 5 bay hard drive dock, they are way too expensive. There was a SATA hat made by Radxa that had 4 ports, so that would have worked perfectly but I don't think they are for sale anywhere anymore. Also, i bought a SATA port multiplier I can use, but apparently, it won't work with most USB to SATA adapters. Some ideas I thought of are a mini PCIe port hat and then a SATA adapter with multiple ports into that, or maybe there is a compute module board somewhere with a few SATA ports. Any ideas? Man, I really wish I could still buy that Radxa sata hat, it would have been perfect.

Comment: Look up Jeff Geerling on youtube

Comment: Yeah I already found his solution, thats why I said about the pcie solution. Im just trying to see if there is something simpler/better that doesn't take like 3 separate boards sticking out in all directions.

Comment: Haven't tried it: https://www.friendlyarm.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=254 seems promising. Otherwise: multple USB-SATA's?

Comment: I'd like to stick with an actual RasPi, but that looks like a good option if I decide to use a different SBC.